# How to create child routes in vue js using Vue-Router and Laravel?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

My application was working fine, until I changed my router.js file slightly to have child routes, and now my app is breaking, I can't see anything on any routes.

I get this error:
`app.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

I can see that it points to this line:

```
var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
```

in this file /public/js/app.js inside this block of code:

```
// on error function for async loading
    __webpack_require__.oe = function(err) { console.error(err); throw err; };

    var jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];
    var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
    jsonpArray.push = webpackJsonpCallback;
    jsonpArray = jsonpArray.slice();
    for(var i = 0; i < jsonpArray.length; i++) webpackJsonpCallback(jsonpArray[i]);
/******/    var parentJsonpFunction = oldJsonpFunction;
```

Has anyone come across something like this? I tried searching on google and there wasn't that much about it, I found something that said they updated their cli@3.0.0-rc.5 to rc.6 and it solved it for that 1 person, but that didn't solve it for me.

Working router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Dashboard from './views/Dashboard';
import Login from './views/Login';
import Register from './views/Register';
import Forms from './views/Forms';
import CandidateProfileCreate from './views/candidate/CandidateProfileCreate';
import CandidateProfileIndex from './views/candidate/CandidateProfileIndex';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [

    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: Dashboard
    },

    {
        path: '/candidate-profile/create',
        name: 'candidate-profile-create',
        component: CandidateProfileCreate
    },

    {
        path: '/candidate-profile',
        name: 'candidate-profile',
        component: CandidateProfileIndex
    },

    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login
    },

    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: Register
    },

    {
        path: '/forms',
        name: 'forms',
        component: Forms
    }
]

const router  = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
});

export default router;
```

Getting error, router.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/home',
        component: Home,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'dashboard',
                component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue')
            },

            {
                path: 'candidate-profile',
                name: 'candidate-profile-index',
                component: () => import('./views/candidate/CandidateProfileIndex')
            },

            {
                path: '/candidate-profile/create',
                name: 'candidate-profile-create',
                component: () => import('./views/candidate/CandidateProfileCreate')
            },
        ],
    },

    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: () => import('./views/Login.vue')
    },

    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'register',
        component: () => import('./views/Register.vue')
    },

    {
        path: '/forms',
        name: 'forms',
        component: () => import('./views/Forms.vue')
    }
]

const router  = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
    linkActiveClass: 'active'
});

export default router;
```

Comment: besides the child routes you changed to "lazy-load" the routes. So my assumption is that you're missing now some modules and thus end up with a "undefined" error. 
To verify this hypothesis, I'd would change the imports back but use child-routes, if that works, the mistake is some where in your imports of the sub modules... hope this makes kinda sense.

Comment: Yes, it does, I changed it back and the app works again. If you lazy load, I guess maybe you need to install a package that I apparently never did. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know lazy load doesnt need any specific package. I'd guess that you are loading some specific packages only within your child components. For example if you include some laravel lib in your CandidateProfileIndex file but also need this module in Dashboard.vue it will fail with lazy loads but work with normal loads

Answer (score 0):

You must create children in object you want.
Like this
if you put path of father element to his children
this page will be open when page create

```
{
    path: '/home',
    component: Home,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue')
        },

        {
            path: 'candidate-profile',
            name: 'candidate-profile-index',
            component: () => import('./views/candidate/CandidateProfileIndex')
        },

        {
            path: '/candidate-profile/create',
            name: 'candidate-profile-create',
            component: () => import('./views/candidate/CandidateProfileCreate')
        },
    ],
},
```